# XSL-FO: Two 8.5x11 "pages" on single 17x11 sheet (double page spread)

Tags: xsl-fo

Is it possible in FO to have two 8.5x11 layouts on a single 17x11 page? I haven't been able to find anything that relates to this. The following image shows what I'm trying to achieve. Is this even possible?

[image: Two Page Spread]

More information for people who weren't clear on the question. I have a large document, where most of the pages will be standard 8.5x11 with a header, footer, and main text. However, some of the pages are large schematics, which will need a 17 x 11 layout. I'm investigating whether it's possible to just create the whole document on an 17 x 11 basis. This means that on most pages I would put two 8.5x11 layouts on a single page, but my schematics would take up the whole page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to make a two-column `fo:region-body` with a *very* wide column gap.

If your FO formatter supports flow maps (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fafm), then you could make your flow flow into two regions (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e7231).

If it's one page, then you'll have to do something like a table in the single `fo:region-before` and single `fo:region-after` to get your two sets of header and footer text.

Note that if it is a single page, you'll only get one page number for the page, so you won't be able to put a different page number in each header/footer, if that's what you are planning.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AH Formatter, then you could generate 8.5x11 pages for the regular content and use a nested `fo:page-sequence` for the occasional 17x11 schematic page.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#fo.page-sequence

The only proviso is that the nested `fo:page-sequence` has to be a child of an `fo:flow`.